# about the following sum : $\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3}+\frac{2}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot5}++\ldots+\frac{n}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot7 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+1)}$

Tags: summation

Any hint about this expression :

$$\frac{1}{1 \cdot 3}+\frac{2}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot5}+\frac{3}{1 \cdot3 \cdot5 \cdot7}+\ldots+\frac{n}{1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot7 \cdot \ldots \cdot (2n+1)}$$

Thanks :)

there must be a trick :)

Comment: If you believe that there must be a trick, I guess you expect a simple result?

Comment: @Fabian it must be simple because this problem can be solved by a child with the age of 13.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{2k}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k+1)}
=\frac1{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k-1)}
-\frac1{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k+1)}\tag{1}
$$
Summing up both sides, where the right hand side telescopes, yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k+1)}
=1-\frac1{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n+1)}\tag{2}
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$ and dividing by $2$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k}{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k+1)}=\frac12\tag{3}
$$

Answer (score 5):

Your $a_n = \dfrac{n}{1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1) \cdot (2n+1)} = \dfrac{n 2^n n!}{(2n+1)!}$.

**Claim**:
$$\sum_{n=1}^m \dfrac{n 2^n n!}{(2n+1)!} = \dfrac12 - \dfrac{2^{m-1} m!}{(2m+1)!}$$

The claim can be easily shown by induction.

Hence, the sum converges to $1/2$.

Comment: How do you get your claim in the first place?

Comment: I figured it out how to get the claim. $a_n = \frac{2^{n-2}(n-1)!}{(2n-1)!} - \frac{2^{n-1}n!}{(2n+1)!}$. If you know the final answer, then it's easier to go backwards and write $a_n$ in the above form.